# How to automate function name in symfony routing?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

Here is the simple route defined in the custom bundle

```
my_admin_route:
    pattern:  /admin/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceCustomBundle:CustomControl:login }
```

Above routing code will call the `CustomControlController`'s method `loginAction()` my question is how can i automate the function name in routing like for each function i don't have to define the  route again there should be one route and call the function automatically as defined  parameter `{name}` in the route like below

```
my_admin_route:
    pattern:  /admin/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceCustomBundle:CustomControl:{name} }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can look at KNP Rad Bundle:
http://rad.knplabs.com/

It does a lot of good things including the one you are talking about

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create a custom route loader, [see](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html).

As far as I know there is currently no out-of-the-box solution to directly map the controllers -> methods -> parameters to a specific route `controller/method/param1/param2` like other frameworks do (CodeIgniter, FuelPHP...).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed this can be achieved with custom route loader as @Onema said.

I can think of two other options, none of which do **exactly** what you wanted but may be of interest:

```
1. Creating a controller action which would just forward request to other actions
2. Using @Route annotation
```

#### 1.

In AdminController create action:

```
public function adminAction($actionName)
{
    return $this->forward('MyBundle:TargetController:' . $actionName);
}
```

#### 2.

Annotation routing since it allows you to define routes without naming them. Name will be implicitly created by convention: [Annotation routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html).

Doesn't do exactly what you wanted but is pretty elegant too if you don't want to make custom route loader:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/dosmt")
 */
public function dosmtAction()
{
    return new Response('smtAction');
}
```

Additionally you can mount all controller actions on a prefix just like with YAML routing:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/dosmt")
     */
    public function dosmtAction()
    {
        return new Response('smtAction');
    }
}
```